# Cannot upgrade Heroku app to ruby 2.1.3

Tags: ruby, heroku, deployment, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upgrade my RoR app from ruby 2.1.2 to ruby 2.1.3.

I've already done it successfully on my staging app, but when I try to push production app (`git push prod master`), I get this log:

```
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
 !
 !     Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl --fail --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/ruby-2.1.3.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf -' failed unexpectedly:
 !
 !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
 !     tar: Child returned status 1
 !     tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I've already tried to repeat the command many times during the last hour, but I never succeeded in deploying the production environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: The tar file is truncated, invalid, or missing.

Comment: You should put your last comment in an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku Support answered me that it's a matter of file permissions and that they are working on to solve this...

### UPDATE

Solved! My problem was that I had set a custom BUILDPACK_URL in my config...